# pandas: drop indices in dataframe A which don't appear in dataframe B

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

**dataframe A:**

```
       value1  value2
0     -0.5     0.5
1      0.5    -0.5
2     -0.5    -1
3      0.5     1
4      0.5     1.5
```

**dataframe B:**

```
       value1  value2
1      15     -5
2     -7      -1
3     -3       10
```

I know that I can "align" dataframe A using the range of index values from dataframe B as follows:

```
df_a[df_b.index[0]:df_b.index[-1]]
```

**result:**

```
       value1  value2
1      0.5    -0.5
2     -0.5    -1
3      0.5     1
```

### Question:

Is this the recommended/idiomatic way to align dataframe A with dataframe B where the index values exist in both?

Comment: How about `df_a.ix[df_b.index]`?

Comment: Do you want to keep the rows of DataFrame A in the order they're currently in? (or can they be 'shuffled' according to B?)

Comment: @ajcr they can be shuffled if need be (although in my particular case they won't need to be)

Comment: @Divakar neat, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) to get overlapping index values.

```
i = dfa.index.intersection(dfb.index)

print(dfa.loc[i])

#    value1  value2
# 1     0.5    -0.5
# 2    -0.5    -1.0
# 3     0.5     1.0

print(dfb.loc[i])

#    value1  value2
# 1      15      -5
# 2      -7      -1
# 3      -3      10
```